# Clone/Mirror Proxmox Drive into Another Proxmox Drive that uses GPT

Tags: partitioning, gpt, fdisk, proxmox

A Proxmox VM (Xpenology DSM) currently has a 4 TB virtual hard disk that has the wrong partition table `msdos`. Instead, one with GPT should be used (to be able to resize it larger than 2 TB).

How can we clone the existing hard disk such that the data remains the same, but uses GPT?

```
$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdc
Disk /dev/sdc: 3.9 TiB, 4294967296000 bytes, 8388608000 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x9694dbae

Device     Boot   Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1          2048    4982527    4980480  2.4G fd Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdc2       4982528    9176831    4194304    2G fd Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdc3       9437184 4194303999 4184866816    2T fd Linux raid autodetect
```

```
$ sudo parted /dev/sdc print | grep -i '^Partition Table'
Partition Table: msdos
```

[image]

Unable to resize 2 TB to 4 TB:

```
$ sudo parted /dev/sdc resizepart 3 100%
Error: partition length of 8379170816 sectors exceeds the
msdos-partition-table-imposed maximum of 4294967295
```

Comment: Do you want to change the partition table on the original to GPT or not? (i.e. you don't need cloning to have that done)

Comment: @TomYan Yes changing the partition to GPT should be fine too, if not cloning

Comment: There's `sgdisk -g`: https://www.mankier.com/8/sgdisk